# Switch between windows of the same pane in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut to switch between the parts of a splitted pane, e.g. in the Debug pane between the Frames list and the variables list (in the default layout), or in docker view between the containers list and the window with logs, properties, variables, ports etc. for that container as in the screenshot below. 
I know I can switch between the tabs of a tabbed window (between Logs, Properties, Environmental Variables etc. in the screenshot below) using `ctrl+Page Up\Down` but I can't find a way to switch focus to that window if I'm currently "in" the container list.

[image: docker view with different windows on the same pane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open request to support it for the debugger:

- [IDEA-167805](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167805) Keyboard navigation in debug tool window

Related requests for Docker:

- [IDEA-155350](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155350) Docker. Container tabs. Switching tabs doesn't work via context menu and doesn't work for two tabs via keyboard
- [IDEA-155835](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155835) Docker. Provide possibility for deleting images/containers using keyboard.

Feel free to [submit your request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) in YouTrack so that it's implemented in one of the future updates.

Comment: IDEA-167805 is finally about to be fixed in 2019.3